# Insert column of same string to front of file in bash

Tags: bash

I want to insert a new column in the front of my tab-delimited file. This column will have a column header but the content of the column will be a single, identical string.

So for example, before:

```
col1    col2    col3     ...
1       2       3        ...
4       5       6        ...
```

after:

```
Inserted_column    col1    col2    col3     ...
A                  1       2       3        ...
A                  4       5       6        ...
```

Is there a way I can do this simply, without having to create a new file?

Comment: Look at `sed`, option 'a' will be useful.

Answer (score 2):

### Insert Columns with GNU sed

This is a great use case for sed. With GNU (not BSD) sed:

```
sed -i.bak '1s/^/col0\t/; 2,$s/^/A\t/' filename
```

Note that I used `col0` rather than `Inserted_column` as a column name to preserve visual alignment in terminal output. That's mostly for debugging. Change it to your column name of choice, either in the sed script or your tab-delimited file, whenever it suits you.

#### Explanation

The `-i` flag turns on in-place editing, with a backup to "filename.bak" in case something goes awry. Just remove the flag if you want to preview the file without actually persisting changes.

The first sed expression, `1s/^/col0\t/`, does the following:

1. uses the address `1` to operate on only the first line of the file
2. replaces the start of the line (`^`) with `col0`+<kbd>tab</kbd> to create the new column header

The second expression, `2,$s/^/A\t/`, does the following:

1. uses the address `2,$` to perform the substitution on lines two through end-of-file
2. substitutes the letter `A` followed by <kbd>tab</kbd> for the start of each line

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i -pe 'if ( $. == 1 ) { $_ = "Inserted_column\t$_"; } else { $_ = "A\t$_" }' file.tsv
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i` : edit the input file in-place (so you do not have to create a separate output file). To create a backup file first, before editing, use `-i.bak`.

`$.` : current line number.

Thus, for the header line (line number 1), it adds the new column name, otherwise it adds the new column value (the same value for all data rows).

**SEE ALSO:**

[`perldoc perlrun`: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score -1):

The sed answer is probably more practical, but here's one that makes heavy use of bash:

```
{ col_1_contents='Inserted Column'; rm myfile.tsv && while IFS= read -r line;do echo "${col_1_contents}${tab}${line}";col_1_contents='A';done > myfile.tsv; } < myfile.tsv
```

A few notes:

- This assumes that $tab contains a tab character
- It would be easy to make a mistake and delete your file while fooling with this approach, so maybe make a backup until you trust it.
- To help understand why it works, take a look at the other [two](https://serverfault.com/a/310104/167681) [answers](https://serverfault.com/a/557566/167681) that inspired me.